# Paypal - How can i debug IPN locally?

Tags: debugging, paypal, localhost

Currently i am working on the sandbox.

Is there any way of forwarding (e.x via my router) the IPN's of the Notification URL to localhost, in order debugging it with Visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible. Check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet).