# what changes i have to do to make my android application work on real mobile

Tags: android

i have an android application works on `emulator` and connect to `server localhost` , send an receive data, i want to make my application on `real mobile` and connect it to localhost via `wireless`, i am using `servlet` to connect from mobile android emulator to localhost server, what is the changes i have to do? `and can I connect to localhost via wireless or i have to buy a real host?`

Comment: why don't you use the local ip address to connect to server?

Comment: @A.A i don't understand what do u mean, but i want to make a graduation project and i want to make my doctor see the application on a real mobile

Comment: Not sure what you are asking there. But if your phone is on the same local network like your development server, then your phone can access your PC via its IP address or host name and the other way around. localhost is by the way an alias that points a network client to itself.

Comment: @NobuGames and if i were on the same network , i just have to connect to the server via server's ip , nothing else?

Comment: well, u used to connect to the local host via 10.0.2.2 in stead you can use the PC IP address to connect to the server as long as your phone and your PC are connected to the same network

Comment: That is correct. Hostname resolution should work too

Comment: @A.A yes you right , i am using 10.0.2.2, now i have just to put the pc's ip instead? nothing else?

Comment: This post for xampp, must help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet

Comment: no nothing else just the PC's IP address

Comment: @AqifHamid can i understand that i have to make some steps on the PC? not just add the pc ip instead of 10.0.2.2 ?

Comment: @A.A great great , and please i want to buy android mobile , can u suggest mobile for me? :)

Comment: and is it hard to install application on real android mobile?

Comment: well, it depends on how much money u want to spend..and it is very easy to install you app on the phone.. it's just like testing it on the emulator you jut hit run

Comment: check this link to have some idea about price range
http://www.myshopping.com.au/PT--31_Mobile_Phones_Android__fs_41957_p2_e__

Comment: you're welcome and good luck with your graduation project :)

Comment: @A.A i found HTC 1V, 4.0, did u thing it is good?

Comment: yes i think it's good.. here's a link for full specs
http://www.htc.com/uk/smartphones/htc-one-v/#specs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the URL and change the IP address from that of the local server to local IP address. Make sure that the mobile device is in the same network with the computer to access the script that fetches the API. Then service the request to get the results in terms of Javascript Object Notation (JSON).