# Address for HttpPost with XAMPP

Tags: android, xampp

I am using XAMMP with Eclipse. If I use android emulator all works but if I use a real phone, Eclipse says that the connection was refused. I am using for the connection:

```
http://10.0.2.2:80
```

Do I need an other address?

Comment: Is your phone connected to the network via wireless?

Comment: The phone is connected via USB. If I don't active anything, Eclipse prompts "connection was refused". If I connect the wifi (Same wifi spot that the PC is) the app freezes when it attemps to connect to the server created by XAMPP and Eclipse doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused because I didn't know where this address comes from (10.0.2.2) but finally I just opened wifi, connect to my wifi spot and change that address putting the subroute of my pc, the local ip. (192.168.1.x). For anyone who wants to connect through internet I found this:

[Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet)