# XAMPP access from external address

Tags: mysql, xampp, server, remote-access

I have my home computer that I am using to learn MySQL that also houses the MySQL  database and XAMPP server. I would also like be able to access it using my school computer when I am at school?

my home computer is windows
my school computer is a mac
and I would like to have full access to change alter and delete everything and anything on my home database, without anyone else able to do the same.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First go through the steps given here, [Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/823124/4381432), to enable remote access of your xampp server.

Then protect your server/application from unwanted users, with any of the following method,

1. allow only particular IP address to access it with [apache access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).
2. use [apache basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).
3. Write PHP code for user authentication

So, only the authenticated users will be able to enter the area where they can run the database scripts.