# Xampp port not working

Tags: xampp, portforwarding

I've got xampp installed on ubuntu. The port which I'm using is 3000. Let's say that my IP address is 123.123.123.123

When from another device I'm checking port 3000 for page 123.123.123.123 it's saying it is open.

When I'm opening page 123.123.123.123:3000 on my computer it's working. However when I'm opening 123.123.123.123:3000 on another device it's not working.

How is it possible? (The port is open)

*it looks like client is being redirected to localhost.

Comment: You need to make your localhost available to other devices. You should make it open to the world.

Comment: when I'm entering 123.123.123.123 from another device, apache is working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are running Xampp server (apache) on port 8000. In this case, your local server access address would be localhost:8000/ or 127.0.0.1:8000/

Let us consider your ip address to be 123.123.123.12. So in your LAN network, the server access address would be 123.123.123.12:8000/. So the address you have used will work in case of devices connected in a LAN network.

Comment: But if my ip is fixed and the port is open, why it's not available outside the LAN?

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet