# How to putt the xampp server online

Tags: php, xampp

I am  working on my final year project. I have needed an interaction between my iPhone app and web services. For this purpose I want to put my website online so that we can easily access through over static IP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following step

1. first go to the apache httpd-xampp.conf file 
   [image]
2. find the line below
3. delete the word "phpmyadmin"
   [image]
4. Restart the apache