# XAMPP can connect via localhost:8080 but not via IP address / 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ip-address

I'm trying to get my localhost XAMPP to broadcast over my IP address. localhost works fine but no luck getting it through to my IP.

I have HTTP TCP Port Forwarding on my router set to 80-8080.

How can I do this ? Any ideas?

Comment: You'r refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet

Comment: You should try debugging via telnet. And your IP address is in same subnet ?

Answer (score 0):

I found some people suffering with the same problem. Some of them solved it by simply running the following command at windows CMD ( Be sure to run it as administrator ).

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```

Good luck and keep me informed if it didn't work for you.

Comment: My IP port 80 works now... :) but it's not connecting to 8080.

127.0.0.1:8080 and localhost:8080 both work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... the HTTP Port Forward IP had to be the same IP as my server (connected device). = )