# How to connect to a server that may be on the network/the current computer

Tags: java, network-programming, client-server

I may be using my Java program (which is initialized by the simple Batch code at the bottom, which may or may not help anything). From my main computer which will connect to *localhost* to get to my MySql server.

I otherwise could be connecting via a laptop, which is on the same Wi-Fi network. Therefore, I believe it would use the *IPv4* address. Lastly, I could connect via a completely different network and would use my IP.

How could I use Java to detect where exactly it is and change which **host** it will connect to while pinging the server?

```
    java -jar thb.jar
    pause
```

Comment: icmp doesn't work that way. The **server** is the host arbitrary clients connect to, it isn't at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I need to be able to connect to my MySql server which is on my computer from basically any location, weather it be via that own computer, a laptop on the same wifi, or from a completely different wifi network. If I am on a different wifi network then localhost will not work, and on the same wifi network I don't believe that using just the regular external IP will work.

Comment: If you are using xamp, then take a look at [Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet) and if you are using wamp ,[TRY THIS](http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/)