# Accessing localhost (xampp) from another network?

Tags: database, xampp, rss, localhost

I've been searching the internet the whole day... I cant find my solution.

What I have: 
- Xampp server installed en configured
- Working website (local)
- Local ip
- External ip
- Port 80 and 8080 allowed in Firewall

What I want: 
- Enter my website and database from any network over my IP address. So, when I am at work, I want to access my website using my (external) IP address.

I am working on a RSS feed in a website and mobile android application, the app is connected (should be) with the website's database. But for this, I need a working IP address.

Can anyone tell me step by step what is have to do? I am not a leek, but not good in English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you can access your XAMPP outside of you computer is possible only if you are in same network on which your computer is connected. I mean; consider the local ip of you computer where xampp is installed is **192.168.100.1** then you can access it from any ip like **192.168.100.xyz**.

Now if you really want to access it from outside of your network you can set up a VPN or port forwarding.

There is a easy solution is to use **[ngrok](http://ngrok.com)**. You can get details here

It is really simple to set up.