# tool like Ngrok to Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet

Tags: xampp, ip, ngrok

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet), I found the best answer for me was : [http://ngrok.com small tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707247/6811378)

This tool is really great, but to add a custom domain you need paying plans

Is there any other tool like Ngrok to Access XAMPP Localhost from Internet

Answer (score 0):

There npm module [localtunnel.me](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) which allows you to specify custom subdomain.

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

then start tunnel like this

```
lt --port 8000 --subdomain yoursubdomain
```

then you'll be able to access it like `subdomain.localtunnel.me`